# jasmine angularjs tests giving inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, unit-testing, recursion

When running my unit tests, sometimes all are OK, sometimes some random test(s) fail for one controller only for some reason I can't see.

The failures report something like:

```
Expected spy exec to have been called with [ Object({}) ] but actual calls were [ Object({}) ]
```

And I really can't find any difference between expected and actual calls.
(using compare tools)

What separates this controller from others is that it contains recursion.
It contains a data-source that returns an array and for every item in that array asynchronous code is executed, something like:

```
var array = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];

//first check the entire array
//then process the entire array
//then do something after the entire array is processed.
checkArray(0, array, object).then(function(){
  processArray(0, array, object).then(function() {
    doSomething(object);
  });
});

function checkArray(index, array, object) {
  return $q(function(resolve) {
    var record = array[index];
    //object is altered in doSomeStuff
    doSomeStuff(record, object).then(function(){
      if(++index !== array.length) {
        return resolve(checkArray(index, array, object));
      } else {
        return resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The actual code may stop halfway checking or processing the array do to some function calling an error, in which case an error popup is shown and the objects final state is compared in the unit tests.

There are however also tests failing again within this same controller (for no reason?) that do not make use of these recursively executed functions.

These spies are however actually called with an object that at the time of calling is slightly different. Jasmine does however not keep the state of an object at calling time, but instead reports the final state of the object.
(that's fine, it's just not as executed, but I don't care)

The code as is functions as required, I would however also like for the tests to run consistently without imaginary errors.
How could I prevent these errors from popping up?

(I see no other things that are really different from other controllers, therefore I assume that this recursion is the cause for my troubles)
When I eliminate the recursion by setting the array size to 1, I however still get the inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objects contained a new Date() object.

Because the difference in seconds was less then 0.5 seconds it did not show as a difference, on many occasions the difference in time was less than a millisecond, and the results of the expected object and actual object were therefore identical.

By replacing the Date object with some random string the test consistently succeeded as expected.